# Passing data from one ASP.NET page to another

Tags: asp.net, global-variables

Ok, this is an very common scenario in web dev, with a very common solution. So what I'm looking for are any *alternative* solutions.

I have some data in PageA, and I'm redirecting to PageB, which has need of this info. I could maybe store it in the querystring, but let's pretend that either it's too complex, or I just don't want it in the querystring.

So I put it in the Session. And then when I get to PageB, I get it out of the Session. This is what we've been doing.

Problem is, the Session is a bag of global variables. And it's bad for all the textbook reasons that global variables are bad. We'll be in some other part of the app and check that variable and do some stuff based on it's value. Then we want to change it, so we have to find out where it was set, only it was set EVERYWHERE. Now we need intimate knowledge of how the user arrived at PageZ to know who and what set that variable.

So if I'm really hating on global variables and spaghetti code, are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Or a Cookie, or write it to a database.

Comment: Love, did you tried form post or CrossPage post back? Maintaining session variables in a common class is also a good practise.

Comment: Yeah, we're looking into the cross page postback now. I like that idea, because it reduces the global variable effect. I just wish I could process some code on pageA first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the

```
 Page.PreviousPage
```

[Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) (Gets the page that transferred control to the current page.)

> Under some circumstances, you might
>   want to post one page to another page.
>   For example, you might be creating a
>   multi-page form that collects
>   different information on each page. In
>   that case, you can configure certain
>   controls (those that implement the
>   IButtonControl interface, such as the
>   Button control) on the page to post to
>   a different target page. This is
>   referred to as **[cross-page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)**.
>   Cross-page posting provides some
>   advantages over using the Transfer
>   method to redirect to another page.

assume you jumped from PageA to _PageB:

```
public partial class _PageB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page PageA = Page.PreviousPage;

        //............... etc
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Are there any downsides to this? How exactly does the process work? I mean, I assume that I won't get to execute any codebehind on pageA between the button getting clicked and arriving at pageB? Would there be a way to do this in code instead of with a button's PostBackURL? Like, I post back to pageA, do some stuff, and then redirect to pageB, allowing pageB to read properties on pageA before it's disposed?

Comment: Use a server transfer for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3x8t37x.aspx ;)

Comment: I looked at the server transfer and it looks cool except for the part about not updating the browser/url. I could see that causing problems. I guess ideally I'd want a cross-browser post but from code. I think i'm going to try the cross browser post in this scenario. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to know who and what set the variable to be able to consume it.  But if I understand correctly you might just dislike the magic strings that using Session[] requires you to rely on.  In that case, why not just wrap the Session object in a helper class?  Maybe something like:

```
class SessionHelper{
  const string FAVORITE_COLOR_KEY = "favcolor"
  public static string FavoriteColor {
    get { return Session[FAVORITE_COLOR_KEY]; }
    set { Session[FAVORITE_COLOR_KEY] = value; }
  }
}
```

That way you can change the magic string "favcolor" to anything you want at any time and not break any code.

Comment: And if you do this you can give your values a default value - in case the user hasn't set it yet.  I would also suggest only setting session variables at strategic times such as login or when the user enters a certain section of the site.

Comment: We actually did this already. We have a SessionManager object so we can use strongly typed variables. The reason we need to know how the variable is set is when we inevitably make a change in the code. We'll be refactoring or changing the business logic and without knowing everywhere that global variable is used, we'll probably be breaking things. Hence global variables == bad.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution, I think (still uses session):  Make an object that has all that you want.  Store that object in session, with a name that is a GUID (non-reusable).  Do a redirect passing just that one GUID on the query string.  Then you know how to access your data that you want.  Set a lifetime of however long you want on the object.

It's still kludgy.  But it works, and doesn't expose all your stuff on the query string, plus other things in your app won't be looking for that specific session key name.  They'd have to enumerate the session variables to get it.

Comment: Interesting idea. Similar my first thought which was a manager object that cleared the data out of session right after it retrieved it. Like a one time variable.

Comment: Right.  However, if you want to be nice to your users, test this very quickly with the back button.  Just do a quick test to see if it behaves like you want.  Of course, this being a .Net app, back might go to a page that was posted back and so then cause a scary warning to the user, and if they say "Go ahead and resubmit" then you'd merely generate a new object/GUID pair, and then destroy it again.  Man, I hate the back button with .Net.  :)

Comment: I hear that. It's like if you had a winforms app and there was button in windows that says 'let the user activate any form at any time and hope the developer can figure out what you mean'. We need 2 things built into a good web framework: 1) clickable controls that cannot be clicked twice - you click it once, it makes the request, and no more clicks until the response, and 2) auto detect of the back button, they get a warning, and if they ignore it, you get bounced to the welcome screen; 'No you can't screw around with my app and expect it to work. Thank you, come again.'